# Redux - Master/Detail state shape

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, redux

Currently, I have a state shape like this for my master-detail view

```
paychecks: {
 summary: {},
 details: {},
};
```

Where summary contains an array of items and details would contain the details for each item that's fetched from the API.

Folder structure

```
/paychecks
  index.js
  /summary
   actions.js
   reducers.js
   index.js
  /details
   actions.js
   reducers.js
   index.js
```

In my views I have two separate screens.  The Master view is hooked up to the `summary` state and the Detail view is hooked up to the `details` state.  This is working fine.

The problem I'm currently facing is that a requirement has come in to display the Paycheck details for the very first paycheck at the very top of the Master View page.  In this case I would need to do the following in this sequence:

1. Fetch the list of paychecks from the API
2. Fetch the details for paychecks[0] from the API

I know I'm supposed to use redux-thunk middleware for this but since both the summary and details are encapsulated from each other, I'm not sure if it makes sense for a summary's action creator to call a details action creator.  Should I create an action creator at the paychecks level that calls fetchPaychecks() and fetchPaycheckDetails() sequentially?

Comment: Could you add detail to each paycheck item and lazy load it when needed? `payChecks = [{summary:"",details:{}},{summary....` this will make impossible state impossible. Having a summary array and hope you'll have a details array at some point that is the same length and order as summery is error prone.